# Своя кнопка загрузки файла на ruby+sinatra+slim

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim

Нашел статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/171743/. Необходимо сделать аналогичное на ruby+sinatra+slim. Вопрос в функции-обработчике события, а именно, как записать имя выбранного файла в div с id='fileformlabel'?

```
var uploaded = document.getElementById("fileformlabel");
uploaded.innerHTML = filename;
```

Как сделать то же самое на ruby+sinatra+slim? Или что нужно еще, чтобы можно это реализовать?

Comment: А что вас смущает то? Вы привели js-код, его что, надо встроить в slim шаблон?